PDFKit library working in Express.js but not in Next.js API route
I'm working on a project where I need to generate PDFs using the pdfkit library. I've managed to get it working in an Express.js server, but I'm facing issues when trying to do the same in a Next.js API route.
Express.js Code (src/index.ts):
import express from 'express';
import PDFDocument from 'pdfkit';
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const doc = new PDFDocument();
  doc.text("hello hello hello HI");
  doc.end();
  doc.pipe(res);
});

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
});

This code works perfectly, generating the PDF as expected when I navigate to the root URL.
Next.js API Route (api/route.ts):
import PDFDocument from 'pdfkit';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const doc = new PDFDocument();
  doc.text("hello hello hello HI");
  doc.end();
  doc.pipe(NextResponse);
}

In the Next.js API route, I'm trying to achieve the same functionality, but it's not working. When I navigate to the corresponding API route in the Next.js app, the PDF is not generated and I get an error.
What I've Tried:

Verified that pdfkit is correctly installed and imported.
Checked that the API route is correctly set up and accessible.

Question:
How can I generate a PDF using pdfkit in a Next.js API route? Is there a different approach I need to take compared to the Express.js implementation?
Is there any option/system to generate the pdf in client browser?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I have posted my answer.Please check it and let me know.

@Subha it's not working still now. and you gave a docs, but it is the same package of pdfkit, not for nextjs

Did you get any error?If yes please share the error.

The problem is that NextResponse object from next.js isn't directly compatible with the pdfkit's piping mechanism. Instead, you need to gather the PDF content into a buffer and then send it as a response.
Try this following approach.
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const doc = new PDFDocument();
  let buffers = [];

  //Collect the PDF data into a buffer
  doc.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));
  doc.on('end', () => {
    const pdfData = Buffer.concat(buffers);
    return NextResponse.next(pdfData);
  });

  //content addition to PDF
  doc.text("hello hello hello HI");
  doc.end();
}

Try the above solution,I think it will work.
You can also check the official docs to know the other details/approach as well.
